# Can SciPy's linprog handle larger numbers?

Tags: python, linear-programming, scipy-optimize

I need to solve linear programs with numbers of sizes up to 10<sup>10</sup>. But `linprog` from the `scipy.optimize` library tells me that such programs are infeasible. As an easy example, the program

> minimize *c* + *d*
> s.t. *c* + 2*d* > 10<sup>10</sup>

is

```
linprog([1, 1], [[-1, -2]], [-10**10])
```

This outputs

```
    con: array([], dtype=float64)
    fun: 645172208.8069017
message: 'The algorithm terminated successfully and determined that the problem is infeasible.'
    nit: 2
  slack: array([-9.03223975e+09])
 status: 2
success: False
      x: array([3.22584169e+08, 3.22588040e+08])
```

It is supposed to output `x: array([0, 0.5e+10])`, in the last line. Can I make it handle larger numbers?

Comment: What's the largest value in place of `10**10` for which it works?

Comment: Even without presolve-related problems, having large numbers like that combined with small ones is deadly for all (advanced) solvers (and debugging is no fun: as internally everything is double, *storing* a 10^50 var is no problem, but the numerical-issues when solving equations is are there). You should try to work around these huge numbers by doing problem-specific *scaling* (try to model it with values around 0).

Comment: @sascha : Will I lose something if I just divided the RHS of the constraint by e.g. 10^7? If the RHS was 9.48235768*10^8, will it drop digits from after the comma and make the result less accurate?

Comment: Floating point numbers have a limited precision anyway, scale doesn't matter. You lose digits either way

Comment: Maybe try a rational LP solver. (Not sure if they handle crazy numbers like that).